# Ubuntu 16.04, drive path changed on its own

Tags: ubuntu, mount, kvm, fstab

So yesterday I had a grub issue that required me to comment out the other two drive sin my fstab that get mounted.
1. an ssd that houses my qcow2 vm.
2. a 1tb seagate

So all I had listed was / and swap.  After I got booted in to the system I notice the ssd which was /dev/sdd changed to /dev/sdc.  OK I thought.. whatever I'll recreate the vm to look at sdc now.  Fast forward to 20 minutes ago, my vm stopped booting, upon further inspection sdc was now back to sdd.  What gives?  What could cause this or where can I look to determine the cause?

Answer (score 1):

All my fault.  I'm the idiot here.. plugged in another 1tb hdd and it just so happens to be on a lower numbered sata port than the ssd so it took sdc and pushed the ssd to sdd.

:(

Answer (score 1):

In the future to prevent this issue I highly recommend using partition UUIDs (as opposed to /dev/sdX naming) in your fstab.  It's super easy to do and will make your life easier, especially for automounting any drives that are likely to change location or might simply be plugged/detected in a different order.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#File_system_UUIDs